# passwordless change user with `sudo su -`

Tags: bash, unix

I want that on my server `fox` user can be/change user and be `user42` in a passwordless way (`fox` user have no password they loging with SSH keys)::

```
srv6:/etc# grep user42 /etc/sudoers
fox     ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/su user42
srv6:/etc#
```

It work well if they do `sudo su user42`:

```
fox@srv6:~$ sudo su user42
user42@akd6:/home/fox$
```

But if I try do have a cleared shell with `sudo su - user42` the NOPASSWD did not work

```
fox@srv6:~$ sudo su - akd
[sudo] password for fox:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not gonna work because `sudo su - user42` does not map to what you have granted in your rule. That rule does not contain the `-` dash and thus it don't map.

How about you do something like:

```
fox ALL=(user42) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

granting fox the right to do anything as user42 without password,

and then `sudo -ui user42` where `-i` will

> -i, --login Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell.  This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login
> will be read by the shell.

Which I believe is your desired outcome.